# How to count multiple values in same column in gridview

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I have some data in SQL server
table:tbtest

```
[User][Value]

User1  100
User1  100
User1  100
User1  100
User1  200
User1  300
User1  300
User1  400
User2  100
User2  100
User2  100
User2  100
User2  200
User2  200
User2  400
```

I want output in gridview1

```
[USER][VALUE][Count of Value]

User1 100                 4 
      200                 1
      300                 2
      400                 1
User2 100                 4
      200                 2 
      400                 1
```

sql asp.net vb language

Comment: Use `COUNT` and `GROUP BY`

Comment: show code pls i don't get

Comment: Google these keywords and try to write the code yourself. Then let us know if you have any issues when running your code.

Comment: Thanks  i can do it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `GROUP BY` in SQL to group your records

[Sample SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/14a8d/14/6)

```
SELECT [user],value, count(*) as count from tblusers group by [user],value ;
```

To group the records in asp.net I advise you to use a repeater control & apply custom templating as required
[Quick guide to nested repeaters](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6140/A-quick-guide-to-using-nested-repeaters-in-ASP-NET)

Comment: Thanks  i can do it :)

Comment: @user3471353 You can up vote this post if you find it helpful. Also, you can mark it as answer whichever post helped you. Damien.

Answer (score 0):

the sql query would be:

```
select user, value, count(value) 
from tbtest 
group by user, value
order by user, value
```

the asp.net part, I don't know about

Comment: Thanks  i can do it :)